# Locating specific item css in joomla 2.5

Tags: css, joomla

Im currently working on a joomla homepage.

Im trying to locate the file that contains css for a specific item with the id of 472.

afaik there is a css file somewhere with css information relative to this object.

i just cant find it. anybody who can help me?

1st edit: when i inspect the element in chrome and change the css of the item to my needs it works as i want it. problem is i cant find the css in my css documents. i already tried looking through the css linked in the resources tab and there was nothing there.

the code can be viewed here: http://www.denz.dk

basicly what i want is to move the "indkøbskurv" to the right side of the menu.

Comment: Use firebug to see all the loaded css files and to inspect any specific element on your homepage.

Comment: Show your working code so we can help you ASAP.

Comment: I already tried that approuch Shaz. Also i added a link to the actual site Dinesh.

Comment: hmm.. it seems it needs to be peer reviewed. the link is http://www.denz.dk - i want to move the menutiem "indkøbskurv" to the right side of the menu and have the rest of the items stay left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu css is being controlled by:

http://www.denz.dk/templates/yougrids/css/menus.css

http://www.denz.dk/templates/yougrids/css/mesh.css

to modify the css for that specific item, add something like this to one of those files:

```
.horiznav .item472 {
/* your style */
}
```